# Navigation Bar Changes Height

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I push my `UIViewController` to the screen from my previous controller it animates the change.  But when it finishes loading it resizes my navigation bar and the jumpy transition makes it look bad.  How can I fix this?  All I'm doing is hiding the navigation bar in Controller A in `viewWillAppear` and showing it in Controller B in `viewDidLoad`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved it.  In `viewDidLoad` of Controller B (the view controller I'm pushing) add the following:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                   forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Then in your `UIViewController`'s XIB make a height constraint on the navigation bar and set it to 68 (from testing the actual line seems to fall in between 68 and 69).  Smooth as silk.

edit: If anyone has any better ideas please add them.  I'll have to modify this solution for screen rotation so its not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all in your **controller A** like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: It still resized the navigation bar.  The animations made it look better but I'd still prefer to not have the navigation bar height resized at all.