# Navigation bar changes height after segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I have an issue with my app that I can't solve. I have  a FirstViewController with a button. when this button is pressed a SecondViewController is pushed. The issue is that the navigation bar changes its height in the secondViewController like (GIF above)

[image: Nav bar changes height]

I didn't write code related to the navigation bar, I checked everything I could think about and tried to delete the segue and re-add it. How can I solve that?

The only thing I found is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414679/navigation-bar-changes-height) but it didn't work for me

Comment: Show us some code please nommis. We need to know how you are presenting it and how you've got it set up.

Comment: There is no code for this part, it is just set up via storyboard! but if you want to have a look the project is on [GitHub](https://www.github.com/nommis/gsb-app), check the development branch

Comment: A GitHub link is even better! :)

Comment: Hey @Gordonium, I didn't exactly found what the issue was but I found how to solve it. It looks like a bug from Xcode. Check my comment under Joe Benton answer. Thanks for your time and your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is making space for a 'prompt' message that appears above the navigation bar as your GIF shows. As you've said you haven't added any code also check the storyboard in case you have entered just a space (as we obviously can't see any text) in the navigation bar prompt box as shown below. Click navigation bar in your view and look at the inspector:

[image: Navigation bar in storyboard inspector]

If there is obviously no space, add text and re-delete it.

Comment: Sooner I accidentally typed something in 'prompt', I deleted it and checked it three time to be sure that there was no space left. But you are right, it started just after I typed text in there. It looks like it still takes into account this even if there is no more message.

Comment: Okay I solved it. I wrote back a prompt message an re-deleted it, and the issue seems to be resolved. Thanks for your time and your help!